# How to read .aef file extension ?

Tags: editor, inputstream, rd

I need to  develop an editor for .aef file extension. But after doing a lot of googling i didn't find out what is the architecture of .aef. How we can read/write .aef file.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To be able to open a .AEF file you have to download the Script Editor from UCCX. Login to CCX Administration -> Tools -> Plugins -> Cisco Unified CCX Editor

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you need to download CiscoUnifiedCCXEditorInstall.exe this file is download from uccx admin page, here you have a link to download the image of UCCX admin, but you need a license.

Here you have a link for free download software:

https://ciscosoftware.mediuscorp.com/market/networkers/homeWork

Answer (score 0):

An aef file for Cicso UCCX is a serialized Java object. Documentation for Java Object Serialization is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/serialization/index.html.

While it may be possible to create 3rd party software to work with these files, it may be impossible or at least difficult to make it complete and accurate without the proprietary Cisco software the contained serialized objects refer to.